# Remove embeded tweets from html when using Newspaper3k

Tags: python-3.x, string, replace

I am using [Newspaper3k](https://newspaper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) for extracting text from online news.

```
from newspaper import Article

urlw = 'https://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=12307959'
article = Article(urlw)
article.download()
article.parse()
string1 = article.text
```

However, I could see there are multiple embedded tweets that I don't need for the analysis. I tried to identify them as the following.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=12307959')
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
article_soup = [s.get_text() for s in soup.find_all('p', {'dir': 'ltr'})]
```

However, I can not figure out a way to remove them from `string1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove html tags using beautiful soup; simply find the html tag and call `extract()` on the html variable. Afterwards, use the soup object to find the article content

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get('https://www.nzherald.co.nz/nz/news/article.cfm?c_id=1&objectid=12307959')
r.raise_for_status() # check for 4xx + 5xx status code
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, "html.parser")

for tweet in soup.find_all('div', {'element-oembed'}):
    tweet.extract() # remove div with class 'element-oembed'

articleTag = soup.find(id='article-content')
print(articleTag.text.strip())
```

Output:

```
'Traffic is backed up for about 9km after an incident near Spaghetti Junction.  The incident happened about 12pm at the Southern Motorway link to the Northwestern Motorway, westbound.  Drivers were asked to avoid the area and consider using an alternative route.     The New Zealand Transport Agency said at 1.25pm the road had reopened but traffic remained heavy between Penrose and the State Highway 1 link - a journey of about 9km.   Advertisement   Advertise with NZME.     "Consider delaying your journey if possible, or be prepared for delays."  Police have cordoned off a section of footpath on Alex Evans Road, above the motorway, in relation to the incident.'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But I just want the text from HTML page without tweets.

Comment: The first bit removes the tweets. The I've added an update afterwards to find content by id and then fetch the text (which should have the tweets removed).